# Always same Type Error occuring when using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I always receive the same error when using npm, e.g. `npm init`

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:3
var supported = require('../../package.json').engines.node
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:3:54)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:155:3)
```

I tried reinstalling, but it didn't solve the problem.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the cache? npm cache clean
It looks like that error is referencing: https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/utils/unsupported.js#L2

Comment: what version of NPM are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running recent `npm` code with an old `package.json` for your `npm` installation. That's odd. (Maybe you started doing an `npm` upgrade and canceled it halfway through?)

If I'm right about this, running this code from your command line should return an old `npm` version number:

```
node -p 'require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/package.json").version'
```

Then get your version of node with `node -v`. Odds are good that there is

If you're `npm` is less than version 6 or your `node` is less than version 12, you will probably want to uninstall Node.js and `npm`, and then reinstalling Node.js (which will reinstall `npm`).

If your version of `npm` is not before version 6, then your `npm` executable is somehow reading a version of the `package.json` that isn't that version. Check for symlink shenanigans by running:

```
node -p 'require("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/../../package.json`).version"
```

If that doesn't return the same version as the first command above, you'll probably want to uninstall Node.js and `npm`, remove all of `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` if the uninstall didn't remove it, and then reinstall Node.js.